# is it possible to terminate a thread with another thread in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to write a program in which many functions run simultaneously. I already figured out that in order to do that I need to use threads.
In my program a routine of heating and rotating an object with different temperatures and velocities has to run for a determined period of time in a loop. Once the time has passed I want the process to continue with my next heating/rotating (...). My idea was to write a "timer thread" that is able to end the current routine in some way, and skip to the next one. Is this possible?

Comment: Not with c++11 std::threads but other libs yes if you can use them. However, it is probably wrong by design to terminate threads from outside.

Comment: and would it be possible, to jump to a specific part of my code if my timer thread has ended?

Comment: "has to run for a determined period of time " - what is the rationale for this?

Comment: what is rationale?

Comment: You can't kill a thread directly but you could code it to use a `std::condition_variable` or `std::atomic<bool>` and use that as a signal to tell the thread to stop and return.  Then your other thread could spin up a new one.

Comment: "rationale" == "why do you think you need to do this?"

Comment: Yes this is absolutely possible. But there are many ways to achieve it so maybe you could be more specific with the code you are writing?

Comment: No. If you want a thread to exit on any condition (time interval passed, user pressed a key, it started raining, whatever), you must have some code *in that thread* to test the condition and exit.

Comment: @NeilButterworth because thats what I was asked for

Comment: If you are ever going to target Windows, note that *TerminateThread* is [never the appropriate action](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811) "The original designers felt strongly that no such function should exist because there was no safe way to terminate a thread, and there's no point having a function that cannot be called safely."

Comment: Running a function for a period of wall-clock time is a strange thing to do - in my entire career I've never come across the need to do such a thing. You may be misunderstaning the problem.

Comment: It is possible to unilaterally kill a thread, but it's not something you should ever do in any non-toy program.  Instead, you should politely ask the thread to voluntarily exit, and then wait for it to go away.  The reason is that if you just kill the thread, it will have no chance to free up any resources it is holding, and this will lead to problems (memory leaks, deadlocks, etc) for your program later on.

Comment: @Galik I have to temperate and rotate a Disk, in order to make some biological processes happen (sorry, can't be more specific). I have a file on which is written how long a certain temperature must be hold, how long and how quick I have to rotate ecc.. There are about 100 different instructions that have to be done one by one. At some point there is the instruction "loop", that tells me that I have to repeat. e.g. step 11 is loop: it tells me that I have to repeat step 5 to 10 for 60 seconds, and then continue with instruction 12.

Comment: I am not sure why a lot of people assume forcibly killing the thread is part of the question. It is just asking if there is a way to end a thread "in some way". Of course that is possible. The main problem with this question IMO is that it is asking a simple "Yes/No" question whereas I suspect some kind of specific help is wanted.

Comment: @tinkerbell Other than telling you "yes this is possible" there is not much anyone can say because you are not asking a very specific question (other than "can it be done"). There are too many possible ways to do this for us to list everything we can think of to provide examples. So, as such, the question seems too broad to me.

Comment: @tinkerbell What you described in your last comment is a simple procedure; You don't even need a thread... `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::duration::seconds(60); while(std::chrono::system_clock::now() < end) { /* do stuff*/ };`

Comment: @Galik So could you tell me one of the possible ways to do it?

Comment: @user1810087 really? But if I do what you are saying, is it going to exit my function/process at any point and jump to the next step?

Comment: Possible ways are: 1) As NathanOliver wrote: `use a std::condition_variable or std::atomic<bool>`... 2) use [boost::threads](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/thread.html). they have a function [interrupt](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.interrupt) and [interruption points](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#interruption_points) 3) use Qthread and it's function [terminate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose most ways to do this are going to involve a shared flag between the working thread and the thread that signals it to stop working.

So you might have something along these lines:

```
// Use a std::atomic_bool to signal the thread safely
void process_stuff(std::atomic_bool& stop_processing)
{
    while(!stop_processing) // do we keep going?
    {
        // do some measurements or action

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1)); // wait for next action
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in another thread ...

```
std::atomic_bool stop_processing{false};

// start thread (use std::ref() to pass by reference)
std::thread proc_thread(process_stuff, std::ref(stop_processing));

// wait for some time...
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

stop_processing = true; // signal end
proc_thread.join(); // wait for end to happen

// now create a new thread...
```

In the initiating thread, by changing the value of the variable `stop_processing` you signal the running thread to stop looping, in which case it ends gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
int main() {
    // first thread
    auto thread1 = std::make_unique<std::thread>([]() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        std::cout << "over\n";
    });

    // disposing to second thread
    std::thread([thread2 = std::move(thread1)](){
        thread2->join();
    }).detach();

    //spinning a new thread
    thread1.reset(new std::thread([]() {
       std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
       std::cout << "next over\n";
    }));
   thread1->join();  

   return 0;
}
```